# Disable full screen or modal for StackEdit

Tags: javascript, jquery, markdown, stackedit

Our goal:

We need the [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/) editor to render exactly at the same place where the textbox is (the way TinyMCE and other editors do) instead of rendering it in modal/fullscreen/covering the entire UI on the HTML page.

We are trying to implement https://stackedit.io/ mark down editor in our application. In order to do that we have set a local instance of https://github.com/benweet/stackedit at following local url say https://localhost:4433.

This would act as a local endpoint http://localhost:8080/app to serve the stackedit editor the way https://stackedit.io/app is having. We set up a local instance so that for editor rendering the remote endpoint of StackEdit domain itself should not hit.

In order to use that endpoint and use stackedit editor on a html page we are using https://benweet.github.io/stackedit.js/ and written the following code to render the editor:

```
var el = document.querySelector('textarea');
    var stackedit = new Stackedit({
        url: 'https://localhost:4433/app'
    });

// Open the iframe
stackedit.openFile({
    name: 'Filename', // with an optional filename
    content: {
        text: el.value // and the Markdown content.
    }
});

// Listen to StackEdit events and apply the changes to the textarea.
stackedit.on('fileChange', (file) => {
    el.value = file.content.text;
});
```

We have taken that code from https://benweet.github.io/stackedit.js/

The issue with the above implementation is that the editor is rendered as a modal and hide all the UI which is on the html page. Here is how it is rendered:

[image]

That is not what we need. In our application there will be multiple editors on a single page and having that editor as full screen or in modal will not serve. Our expectation with the editor is to make StackEditor render like popular TinyMCE edito i.e it should be rendered exactly at the same position where the textbox is.

TinyMCE editor:

[image]

This is how StackExchange editor comes:

[image: /]

So coming back to my original question, is it even possible with StackEdit to implement the editor in place where the textbox is instead of modal or full screen?

EDIT:

I went to following links with similar request and got no success there also:

https://github.com/benweet/stackedit.js/issues/10

https://github.com/benweet/stackedit.js/issues/14

https://github.com/benweet/stackedit.js/issues/26

Comment: Hi, got any solution?